# Invalid object name error on SELECT statement alias

Tags: sql, sql-server

I've written a SQL query which assigns an alias to each of two nested SELECT statements and attempts to join on these aliases.

My SQL query is as follows:

```
SELECT EmpID,
       (SELECT EmpID
              ,Count(*) * 8 AS [FullDayHours]
        FROM [database].[dbo].[tblLogTimes] 
        WHERE ActivityID = 43 
        AND WorkDate BETWEEN '2015-12-31 00:00:00.000' AND '2016-09-30 00:00:00.000'
        GROUP BY EmpID) AS [Rec1]
      ,(SELECT EmpID
              ,(Count(*) * 4) AS [HalfDayHours] 
        FROM [database].[dbo].[tblLogTimes] 
        WHERE ActivityID = 44 
        AND WorkDate BETWEEN '2015-12-31 00:00:00.000' AND '2016-09-30 00:00:00.000'
        GROUP BY EmpID) AS [Rec2]
FROM [database].[dbo].[tblLogTimes] E
INNER JOIN [Rec1] ON E.EmpID = [Rec1].EmpID
INNER JOIN [Rec2] ON E.EmpID = [Rec2].EmpID
```

On attempted execution of the query, I'm experiencing an error: Invalid object name 'Rec1'.

I've tried various arrangements and configurations of the query component substatements but to no avail.

Insights, advice would be very welcome.
Thanks for looking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe this is what you're after instead moving the subqueries to the `join`:

```
SELECT EmpID, FullDayHours, HalfDayHours
FROM [StaffSuite].[dbo].[tblLogTimes] E
INNER JOIN (SELECT EmpID
              ,Count(*) * 8 AS [FullDayHours]
        FROM [StaffSuite].[dbo].[tblLogTimes] 
        WHERE ActivityID = 43 
        AND WorkDate BETWEEN '2015-12-31 00:00:00.000' AND '2016-09-30 00:00:00.000'
        GROUP BY EmpID) AS [Rec1] ON E.EmpID = [Rec1].EmpID
INNER JOIN (SELECT EmpID
              ,(Count(*) * 4) AS [HalfDayHours] 
        FROM [StaffSuite].[dbo].[tblLogTimes] 
        WHERE ActivityID = 44 
        AND WorkDate BETWEEN '2015-12-31 00:00:00.000' AND '2016-09-30 00:00:00.000'
        GROUP BY EmpID) AS [Rec2] ON E.EmpID = [Rec2].EmpID
```

---

However you could use `conditional aggregation` to simplify it further:

```
SELECT EmpID, FullDayHours, HalfDayHours
FROM [StaffSuite].[dbo].[tblLogTimes] E
INNER JOIN (SELECT EmpID
              ,Count(case when activityid = 43 then 1 end) * 8 AS [FullDayHours]
              ,Count(case when activityid = 44 then 1 end) * 4 AS [HalfDayHours]
        FROM [StaffSuite].[dbo].[tblLogTimes] 
        WHERE ActivityID IN (43,44)
        AND WorkDate BETWEEN '2015-12-31 00:00:00.000' AND '2016-09-30 00:00:00.000'
        GROUP BY EmpID) AS [Rec1] ON E.EmpID = [Rec1].EmpID
```